# How to get a topic name in a callback function (Python, Ros2)

Tags: ros2, camera, callback, topic

I have two cameras subscribing camera1/image_raw and camera2/image_raw respectively. And both subscribers call image_callback when they received any topic. I want to show camera1 image in window1 and camera2 image in window2 while using the same callback function.

So, in the callback function, I would like to determine the topic name (or which subscriber executed the callback function) and if it is camera1, show it in window1 and otherwise in window2.

But, I can't figure out how to determine which subscriber executed the callback in python. Can anyone help me out with this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is going to be to have two separate callback functions which wrap some common set of code. You can make this a lot cleaner using python's lambda function feature. For example, in ROS 1:

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def callback(data, source):
    rospy.loginfo(f"I heard {data.data} from {source}")

def listener():
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("chatter_1", String, lambda data: callback(data, 1))
    rospy.Subscriber("chatter_2", String, lambda data: callback(data, 2))
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

and in ROS 2:

```
import rclpy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def callback(data, source):
    rospy.loginfo(f"I heard '{data.data}' from {source}")

def listener():
    rclpy.init()
    node = rclpy.create_node('listener')

    node.create_subscription(String, 'chatter_1', lambda msg: callback(msg, 1), 10)
    node.create_subscription(String, 'chatter_2', lambda msg: callback(msg, 2), 10)

    rclpy.spin(node)
    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```